# Need help to add front-end on slatwall eCommerce

Tags: coldfusion, e-commerce, lucee

I am trying to build the eCommerce store by using Slatwall and lucee. Slatwall is the ColdFusion based eCommerce framework. The admin part is working fine. But I could not create the user side. I also referred the slatwall documentation. But no luck I couldn't seen any clear example and document for adding the front end on slatwall. If anyone knows help me please?

[Slatwall frontend document](http://www.slatwallcommerce.com/developer/developer-guide/frontend-development/)

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but ... to avoid your question being closed as unclear/too broad please edit the question to a) Elaborate on what you mean by "could not create the user side" and B) post the code you have tried so far with a brief description of the result.

Comment: Let explain my needs. I have added the 10 products on slatwall admin side. Now I need to list out all products on user side and user can able to purchase the product. But in that slatwall document is not clear for create the front end for cart.

Comment: Have you tried looking at or asking in their developer center? http://www.slatwallcommerce.com/developer/

Comment: Yes.  No luck. If we need to customise it they will help and also they charged for their service. It's a open source. But poor documentation. But it is very good ecom framework in coldfusion platform.

Comment: Isn't slatwall just that, an ecommerce backend, which you're supposed to implement into your existing front-end?

Answer (score 1):

As OP says, SlatWall has excellent $upport, that's where they make a living. You now have three choices for a front end:

1) Slatwall latest versions have their own integrated CMS now. I'd recommend you export your product info, install the latest Slatwall, import the data back in.

2) Load MuraCMS, an Open Source Content Management (i.e. front-end) system that has integration to Slatwall (or the other way round, IIRC)

3) Roll your own in ColdFusion after learning ins and outs of the Slatwall api. Not recommended unless you're already CF experienced and have some previous experience with an api, any api.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I am going to answer this question even though its months old, for anyone else that views this.

You have a couple options here but the easiest way:

**There is a complete example of a fully implemented Slatwall site including product listing pages, shopping-cart, and checkout included with Slatwall**.

You may view the sample site by visiting http://{yourslatwallsite}/meta/sample

On the sample site, you can choose from the menu to view your products, add them to your cart, or checkout. Make sure your products are both active and published in the admin or you will not see them on the sample site. If you go through the .cfm pages that makeup the sample site, there are many examples documented (as comments in the code). Note that the actual .cfm files will be stored in /public/views/xxx.cfm and the meta folder just references them. /public/views/templates/slatwall-productlisting.cfm for example has complete examples on listing products on the frontend.

The sample site is powerful enough that you could restyle it and use it as your store